# How do you have the computer change its choice depending on the input of the player in this game of rock, paper, scissors?

Tags: python

I want the computer to follow a win-stay, lose-switch strategy but I can't seem to get the computer to change its option from rock. Please help!

```py
import random


def game():

    game_start
    computer_count = 0
    user_count = 0

    while True:
        base_choice = ['scissors', 'paper', 'rock']
        computer_choice = 'rock'

        user_choice = input('(scissors, paper, rock) Type your choice: ').strip().lower()
        print()
        computer_wins = 'The computer wins!'
        you_win = 'You win!'

        print(f'You played {user_choice}, the computer played {computer_choice}')
        if user_choice == 'scissors' and computer_choice == 'rock':
            computer_choice = 'rock'
        elif user_choice == 'paper' and computer_choice == 'scissors':
            computer_choice = 'scissors'
        elif user_choice == 'rock' and computer_choice == 'paper':
            computer_choice = 'paper'
            print(computer_wins)
            computer_count += 1

        if user_choice == 'rock' and computer_choice == 'scissors':
            computer_choice = 'paper'
        elif user_choice == 'scissors' and computer_choice == 'paper':
            computer_choice = 'rock'
        elif user_choice == 'paper' and computer_choice == 'rock':
            computer_choice = 'scissors'
            print(you_win)
            user_count += 1

        else:
            if user_choice == computer_choice:
                print('Its a draw!')
                computer_count += 0
                user_count += 0

        print(f'Computer: {computer_count} - You: {user_count}')
        print()


game()
```

Comment: Yeah that's gonna be because you define the computer_choice as "rock" every iteration of the while loop. Take it out of the loop.

Comment: How can I make the computer make an initial choice that can be random? Would I do something like computer = random.randint(1,3)? And could I place it before the loop?

Comment: Close, using the data structures you have above, computer_choice = base_choice[random.randint(0,2)] would return a random value from the list defined in base_choice. randint(1,3) would never select 'scissors' and sometimes return an out of range exception.

Comment: That makes sense, I totally messed that one up haha I keep forgetting to start with 0. However, when I add this outside of the loop, I get an error saying base_choice is not defined. Do I need to move the base_choice outside of the loop as well?

Comment: Yeah, you have to define base_choice before you call it. However, you could leave base_choice and computer_choice in the while loop, and remove most of the rest of the code, because the computers choice would be random for each iteration of the while loop - so you don't have to define the next one. You'd have to add some logic for the "win stay, lost switch" strategy, but it'd be a bit cleaner.

Comment: The [tag:pygame] tag is for questions about the [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) package.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you put `computer_choice = 'rock'` *inside* the while loop. Having inside causes it to be reset to rock for every play.

Another issue is that your if statements only prints who wins and increases count for the last one.

You can also compress the if statements a little, but that wasn't part of the question, so I didn't do it here.

```
game_start
computer_count = 0
user_count = 0
def game():
    computer_choice = 'rock'
    while True:
        #base_choice = ['scissors', 'paper', 'rock']
        # no point in having an unused list
        user_choice = input('(scissors, paper, rock) Type your choice: ').strip().lower()
        print()
        computer_wins = 'The computer wins!'
        you_win = 'You win!'

        print(f'You played {user_choice}, the computer played {computer_choice}')
        if user_choice == 'scissors' and computer_choice == 'rock':
            computer_choice = 'rock'
            print(computer_wins)
            computer_count += 1
        elif user_choice == 'paper' and computer_choice == 'scissors':
            computer_choice = 'scissors'
            print(computer_wins)
            computer_count += 1
        elif user_choice == 'rock' and computer_choice == 'paper':
            computer_choice = 'paper'
            print(computer_wins)
            computer_count += 1

        if user_choice == 'rock' and computer_choice == 'scissors':
            computer_choice = 'paper'
            print(you_win)
            user_count += 1
        elif user_choice == 'scissors' and computer_choice == 'paper':
            computer_choice = 'rock'
            print(you_win)
            user_count += 1
        elif user_choice == 'paper' and computer_choice == 'rock':
            computer_choice = 'scissors'
            print(you_win)
            user_count += 1

        else:
            if user_choice == computer_choice:
                print('Its a draw!')
                # no point in adding 0


        print(f'Computer: {computer_count} - You: {user_count}')
        print()
game()
```

In response to your making it random comment, you need to import the `random` module.

Here, the `base_choice` is used, so uncomment it and it'll work:

```
import random #place at beginning of code
# can instead do `from random import choice`

base_choice = ['scissors', 'paper', 'rock']
# needs to be before you use it in random.choice

# to get random choice, do
computer_choice = random.choice(base_choice)
```

Comment: When I place computer_choice = random.choice(base_choice) outside of the loop, it gives me an error saying that base_choice is not defined. Should I move the base_choice outside of the loop as well?

Comment: Yeah, you can even move it outside of the function if you want.